# Different validation groups for method parameters and return value

Tags: java, spring, validation

I would like to use different validation groups for a method's parameters and its return value.
I am trying to Spring's @Validated annotation to achieve this. For example:

```
public interface UserOperations {

    @Validated({ResponseGroup.class})
    @Valid 
    User createUser(@Validated({RequestGroup.class}) @Valid User user);

}
```

It appears that return value is in fact getting validated against `ResponseGroup`, however the method argument `user` is getting validated against both `ResponseGroup` and `RequestGroup`. I see why this is happening when I look at: `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor#invoke`

Is there an elegant way to apply one validation group to the method argument and different validation group to the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method `MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke` looks for validation groups defined in an `@Validated` annotation on each method, or on the class, but not on individual parameters. The validation groups that are specified will be applied to the parameters as well as the return value.

In order to have different validation groups get applied to parameters and return values, you don't even need to specify groups inside the @Validated annotation; instead you can use @javax.validation.groups.ConvertGroup.

```
@Validated
public interface UserOperations {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = User.Existing.class)
    User create(@NotNull @Valid @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = User.New.class) User user);
}

public interface User {

    @Email(groups = {New.class, Existing.class})
    String getEmail();

    @Null(groups = {Existing.class})
    @NotNull(groups = {New.class})
    String getPassword();

    interface Existing {
    }

    interface New {
    }
}
```

Given the above, when `UserOperations.create` is called, the argument for `user` will get validated against the `New` group (must have a non-null password), while the return value will get validated against the `Existing` group (must have a null password).

As a side note, I realized Spring's method validation doesn't behave exactly in the same way as Spring MVC's automatic validation of `@Valid @RequestBody`. Additionally, If method validation is turned on for a Controller (has an `@Validated` annotation on the class), then the same `@RequestBody` method argument will get validated twice: once by standard method interceptor validation and once by MVC. To avoid MVC's validation on `@RequestBody` arguments of a given controller, I did the following:

```
@RestController
public class UserController implements UserOperations {
    ... 

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(null);
    }

    ...
}
```